# how to divide two different SQL query to get a single count, when one is giving me count x and other is y

Tags: sql

I am having this two query one is giving me count of number of defects :

```
SELECT T1.PROJECT_NAME,
       T1.REQUEST_TYPE,
       COUNT( DISTINCT T1.REFERENCE_ID) AS REFERENCE_ID
FROM RIDW.VW_REQUEST T1    
WHERE T1.PROJECT_ID = 4  
  AND T1.REQUEST_TYPE = 'Defect' 
  AND T1.ISSOFTDELETED = 0
  AND (T1.REQUEST_ID <> -1 AND T1.REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY T1.PROJECT_NAME,
         T1.REQUEST_TYPE
```

and other is giving me count for total number of test cases:

```
SELECT T2.PROJECT_NAME,
       COUNT( DISTINCT T2.REFERENCE_ID) AS REFERENCE_ID
FROM RIDW.VW_TESTCASE T2
WHERE T2.PROJECT_ID = 6 
  AND T2.ISSOFTDELETED = 0
  AND (T2.TESTCASE_ID <> -1 AND T2.TESTCASE_ID IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY T2.PROJECT_NAME
```

I want a combine query which will give me count= defects/total test cases

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: what is your rdbms

Comment: I am using IBM db2

Comment: Still without sample data and expected output is very hard to understand what you need.